# Python loadtxt and genfromtxt truncate strings

Tags: python, string, numpy, truncated, genfromtxt

I have a 2-column array mixed type array that I need to read in and reshape into a data cube. I've got most of it working, but for some reason both numpy.loadtxt and np.genfromtxt drop everything after the 8th character from the string part of the tuple. I have 25 blocks of 8 parameter-value pairs corresponding to stars of varying masses and metallicities. For instance, Teff `\t\t 5.2739E+3` (there are 2 tabs between the string and the float) converts to a key-value pair just fine, but `MASS/MSUN  \t\t 0.800` gets converted to `'MASS/MSU':0.800` instead of  `'MASS/MSUN':0.800` like I expected. Similarly,`LOG(L/LSUN) \t\t 0.0522` becomes `'LOG(L/LS': 0.0522` instead of `'LOG(L/LSUN)': 0.0522`
Why are the last characters in the strings falling off?
I've tried setting the delimiters to only tabs, only tabs and newlines (didn't seem to like that), commented out the lines between blocks, etc. Seems like no matter what I do, the character limit for each string is stuck at 8. There must be a string subtype I need to declare. I've made a workaround, it just bothers me.

This is my code (I'm using the Spyder GUI, BTW):

```
>>>f=np.genfromtxt("zamsdata.txt",dtype=(str,float))
>>>zcube = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))
>>>infotups=[]
>>>for row in f:
>>>    if 'MASS' in row[0]:
>>>        mass=str(row[1])
>>>        continue #rows are in repeating order of MASS, X, Y, Pc, Tc, R, L, Te, LOG(Te) & LOG(L/LSUN)
>>>    if 'X' in row[0]:
>>>        hydfrac=str(row[1])
>>>        continue
>>>    else:
>>>        infotups=infotups+[[hydfrac,mass,str(row[0]),row[1]]]
>>>        
>>>for l,m,a,o in infotups:
>>>    zcube[l][m][a].append(o)
```

Comment: nice question, it would be even better if you could include one example of the input data and the expected output...

Comment: I had hoped it would be self-explanatory that the input is just being converted verbatim from a tuple to a key: value pair, but I guess it never hurts to add extra clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the data type of a field is specified to be `str`, it looks like the default size assigned to the field by `genfromtxt` is eight characters.  If you know that the maximum number of characters is, say, 12, you could use `dtype=['S12', float]`.  (Note that I've used a list, not a tuple.)  You could also use `dtype=None`, which tells `genfromtxt` to figure out the data type of each field from what it finds in the file.

Comment: Setting dtype=None truncated the strings the same way, but your first suggestion worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Use `dtype=None` worked for me with a file containing 25 lines, with one string column and one floating point column, where the maximum length of a string was 15.  I'm using numpy version 1.8.2.